# Printing a variable results in printing its type

Tags: c#, printing

I have declared: ListItem **contractItem**;
A process that retrieves data from SQL fills **contractItem**.

**contractItem** is then written back to SQL.Works weel. All info in **contractItem** is as expected.

But, i need to write certain values in **contractItem** to a log-file.

```cs
String sTxt = "Subject = " + contractItem.FieldValues["Subject"].ToString();
```

The contents of sTxt = "Subject = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"

instead of what I expected it to be: "Subject = Documentation e-content 365"

What am I doing wrong?

```cs
String sTxt = "Subject = " + contractItem.FieldValues["Subject"].ToString();
```

or

```cs
String sTxt = "Subject = " + contractItem.FieldValues["Subject"];
```

both result in "Subject = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue"

Comment: What software language is this?

Comment: The language I use is C#

Comment: The issue is most probably you are calling the `.toString()` method. If the type does not override the method it returns the type name. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

The result of `contractItem.FieldValues["Subject"]` is apparently a [`FieldLookupValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee540961(v=office.15)) and apparently that doesn't override `ToString()`. However, it does expose a `LookupValue` property.

So I suspect you want something like:

```cs
var lookup = (FieldLookupValue) contractItem.FieldValues["Subject"];
string subject = lookup.LookupValue;
strinug text = "Subject = " + subject; // Or just $"Subject = {subject}"
```